# MongoDB find() query scans documents twice (duplicate cursor used) when using limit() + sort()?

Tags: mongodb

I'm fairly new to MongoDB, though I haven't been able to find an explanation for what I'm seeing.

I have a small dataset of about 200 documents, when I run the following query:
`db.tweets.find({user:22438186})`
I get *n* / *nscannedObjects* / *nscanned* / *nscannedObjectsAllPlans* / *nscannedAllPlans* all at **9**. The cursor is *BtreeCursor user_1*. All good.

---

### Introducting Sort()

If I append a sort to the query:
`db.tweets.find({user:22438186}).sort({created_at:1})`
*nscannedObjectsAllPlans* / *nscannedAllPlans* have increased to **30**. I can see under the *allPlans* field:

```
[
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor user_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 9,
    "nscannedObjects" : 9,
    "nscanned" : 9,
    "scanAndOrder" : true,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "user" : [ 
            [ 
                22438186, 
                22438186
            ]
        ]
    }
},
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor created_at_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 2,
    "nscannedObjects" : 21,
    "nscanned" : 21,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "created_at" : [ 
            [ 
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                }, 
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
]
```

*BtreeCursor created_at_1* scanned 21 documents and matched 2? I'm not sure what is going on here as I thought `sort()` was applied to the documents returned by `find()`, which appears to be 9 from the *user_1* index. In writing this up I'm gathering from the *allPlans* field that it's also using my *created_at_1* index for some reason.

---

### Limit(>n) combined with Sort() == duplicate cursor & document scans?

When I append `limit(10)` or higher, *n* remains at 9, *nscannedObjects* / *nscanned* are both at **18** and *nscannedObjectsAllPlans* / *nscannedAllPlans* now return **60**. **Why have all but *n* doubled?** The *cursor* is now *QueryOptimizerCursor*, There is a *clauses* field in my `explain(true)` results, both child objects are exactly the same, the same cursor was used twice causing the duplication? Is this behaviour normal?

```
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor user_1",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 9,
"nscannedObjects" : 9,
"nscanned" : 9,
"scanAndOrder" : true,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"indexBounds" : {
    "user" : [ 
        [ 
            22438186, 
            22438186
        ]
    ]
}
}
```

I've tried a few different limit values and noticed that using a limit of 9, *nscannedObjects* / *nscanned* both return back to values of 9 and *nscannedObjectsAllPlans* / *nscannedAllPlans* drop down to **29**, decrementing by 1 as I decrement the limit.

Under clauses however the 2nd child object is not the same as limit queries of 10 and higher. The *cursor* field now displays *BtreeCursor* omitting *user_1* for some reason, all the *n* fields have a value of **0** instead of 9, besides that the rest of the object is the same. For all of these limit queries *allPlans* field lists the *clauses* field and another for *BtreeCursor created_at_1* (which is used as the cursor for a query with limit of 1).

---

## Actual Question

So what exactly is causing my documents to be scanned twice when `limit()` and `sort()` are both used in a `find()`? The issue only seems to happen if the limit exceeds either *nscannedObjects* or *nscanned*. When querying with only `limit()` or `sort()` documents are not scanned twice.

### Update

Sorry for the confusion, the first code block shows cursor data under the **allPlans** field. The actual cursor used was `*BtreeCursor user_1*`.

The 2nd code block is from a query with `limit()` and `sort()`. I am providing cursor data listed under **clauses**, the *clauses* field lists the same cursor information twice (duplicate). The actual *cursor* field for that query was `*QueryOptimizerCursor*`. The duplicate cursors under *clauses* are `*BtreeCursor user_1*`.

I've since added a compound index {user:1, created_at:1}, The results for *n* fields is 9, and *nAllPlans* 18. Regardless of `limit()` value or usage with `sort()`. For some reason under *allPlans* my original *user_id_1* index is still being run alongside the new compound index. If a limit is applied to the query instead of the index *user_id_1*/*BtreeCursor user_1* being used, *QueryOptimizerCursor* with the two cursors in *clauses* is being used.

I've been looking into this further and it seems to be the Query Planner uses other indexes in parallel and selecting the optimal index result? I'm not sure if each time I perform this query this 'competition' occurs again or if it is cached.

`db.tweets.find({user:22438186}).sort({created_at:1}).limit(10)`
Running the query without the compound index produces the following:

```
{
"clauses" : [ 
    {
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor user_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 9,
        "nscannedObjects" : 9,
        "nscanned" : 9,
        "scanAndOrder" : true,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
            "user" : [ 
                [ 
                    22438186, 
                    22438186
                ]
            ]
        }
    }, 
    {
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor user_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 9,
        "nscannedObjects" : 9,
        "nscanned" : 9,
        "scanAndOrder" : true,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
            "user" : [ 
                [ 
                    22438186, 
                    22438186
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
],
"cursor" : "QueryOptimizerCursor",
"n" : 9,
"nscannedObjects" : 18,
"nscanned" : 18,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 60,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 60,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"nYields" : 0,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 0,
"allPlans" : [ 
    {
        "clauses" : [ 
            {
                "cursor" : "BtreeCursor user_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "n" : 9,
                "nscannedObjects" : 9,
                "nscanned" : 9,
                "scanAndOrder" : true,
                "indexOnly" : false,
                "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "user" : [ 
                        [ 
                            22438186, 
                            22438186
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }, 
            {
                "cursor" : "BtreeCursor user_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "n" : 9,
                "nscannedObjects" : 9,
                "nscanned" : 9,
                "scanAndOrder" : true,
                "indexOnly" : false,
                "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "user" : [ 
                        [ 
                            22438186, 
                            22438186
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "cursor" : "QueryOptimizerCursor",
        "n" : 9,
        "nscannedObjects" : 18,
        "nscanned" : 18,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0
    }, 
    {
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor created_at_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 3,
        "nscannedObjects" : 42,
        "nscanned" : 42,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
            "created_at" : [ 
                [ 
                    {
                        "$minElement" : 1
                    }, 
                    {
                        "$maxElement" : 1
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
],
"server" : "HOME-PC:27017",
"filterSet" : false,
"stats" : {
    "type" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
    "works" : 43,
    "yields" : 0,
    "unyields" : 0,
    "invalidates" : 0,
    "advanced" : 9,
    "needTime" : 32,
    "needFetch" : 0,
    "isEOF" : 1,
    "children" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "OR",
            "works" : 42,
            "yields" : 0,
            "unyields" : 0,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "advanced" : 9,
            "needTime" : 32,
            "needFetch" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "dupsTested" : 18,
            "dupsDropped" : 9,
            "locsForgotten" : 0,
            "matchTested_0" : 0,
            "matchTested_1" : 0,
            "children" : [ 
                {
                    "type" : "SORT",
                    "works" : 21,
                    "yields" : 0,
                    "unyields" : 0,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "advanced" : 9,
                    "needTime" : 10,
                    "needFetch" : 0,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "forcedFetches" : 0,
                    "memUsage" : 6273,
                    "memLimit" : 33554432,
                    "children" : [ 
                        {
                            "type" : "FETCH",
                            "works" : 10,
                            "yields" : 0,
                            "unyields" : 0,
                            "invalidates" : 0,
                            "advanced" : 9,
                            "needTime" : 0,
                            "needFetch" : 0,
                            "isEOF" : 1,
                            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                            "forcedFetches" : 0,
                            "matchTested" : 0,
                            "children" : [ 
                                {
                                    "type" : "IXSCAN",
                                    "works" : 10,
                                    "yields" : 0,
                                    "unyields" : 0,
                                    "invalidates" : 0,
                                    "advanced" : 9,
                                    "needTime" : 0,
                                    "needFetch" : 0,
                                    "isEOF" : 1,
                                    "keyPattern" : "{ user: 1 }",
                                    "isMultiKey" : 0,
                                    "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['user']: [22438186.0, 22438186.0]",
                                    "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                    "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                                    "matchTested" : 0,
                                    "keysExamined" : 9,
                                    "children" : []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "type" : "SORT",
                    "works" : 21,
                    "yields" : 0,
                    "unyields" : 0,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "advanced" : 9,
                    "needTime" : 10,
                    "needFetch" : 0,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "forcedFetches" : 0,
                    "memUsage" : 6273,
                    "memLimit" : 33554432,
                    "children" : [ 
                        {
                            "type" : "FETCH",
                            "works" : 10,
                            "yields" : 0,
                            "unyields" : 0,
                            "invalidates" : 0,
                            "advanced" : 9,
                            "needTime" : 0,
                            "needFetch" : 0,
                            "isEOF" : 1,
                            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                            "forcedFetches" : 0,
                            "matchTested" : 0,
                            "children" : [ 
                                {
                                    "type" : "IXSCAN",
                                    "works" : 10,
                                    "yields" : 0,
                                    "unyields" : 0,
                                    "invalidates" : 0,
                                    "advanced" : 9,
                                    "needTime" : 0,
                                    "needFetch" : 0,
                                    "isEOF" : 1,
                                    "keyPattern" : "{ user: 1 }",
                                    "isMultiKey" : 0,
                                    "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['user']: [22438186.0, 22438186.0]",
                                    "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                    "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                                    "matchTested" : 0,
                                    "keysExamined" : 9,
                                    "children" : []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

With the compound index:

```
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor user_1_created_at_1",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 9,
"nscannedObjects" : 9,
"nscanned" : 9,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 18,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 18,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 0,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 0,
"indexBounds" : {
    "user" : [ 
        [ 
            22438186, 
            22438186
        ]
    ],
    "created_at" : [ 
        [ 
            {
                "$minElement" : 1
            }, 
            {
                "$maxElement" : 1
            }
        ]
    ]
},
"allPlans" : [ 
    {
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor user_1_created_at_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 9,
        "nscannedObjects" : 9,
        "nscanned" : 9,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
            "user" : [ 
                [ 
                    22438186, 
                    22438186
                ]
            ],
            "created_at" : [ 
                [ 
                    {
                        "$minElement" : 1
                    }, 
                    {
                        "$maxElement" : 1
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    }, 
    {
        "clauses" : [ 
            {
                "cursor" : "BtreeCursor user_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "n" : 0,
                "nscannedObjects" : 9,
                "nscanned" : 9,
                "scanAndOrder" : true,
                "indexOnly" : false,
                "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "user" : [ 
                        [ 
                            22438186, 
                            22438186
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }, 
            {
                "cursor" : "BtreeCursor ",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "n" : 0,
                "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                "nscanned" : 0,
                "scanAndOrder" : true,
                "indexOnly" : false,
                "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "user" : [ 
                        [ 
                            22438186, 
                            22438186
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "cursor" : "QueryOptimizerCursor",
        "n" : 0,
        "nscannedObjects" : 9,
        "nscanned" : 9,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0
    }
],
"server" : "HOME-PC:27017",
"filterSet" : false,
"stats" : {
    "type" : "LIMIT",
    "works" : 11,
    "yields" : 0,
    "unyields" : 0,
    "invalidates" : 0,
    "advanced" : 9,
    "needTime" : 0,
    "needFetch" : 0,
    "isEOF" : 1,
    "children" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "FETCH",
            "works" : 11,
            "yields" : 0,
            "unyields" : 0,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "advanced" : 9,
            "needTime" : 0,
            "needFetch" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "forcedFetches" : 0,
            "matchTested" : 0,
            "children" : [ 
                {
                    "type" : "IXSCAN",
                    "works" : 10,
                    "yields" : 0,
                    "unyields" : 0,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "advanced" : 9,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needFetch" : 0,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "keyPattern" : "{ user: 1, created_at: 1 }",
                    "isMultiKey" : 0,
                    "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['user']: [22438186.0, 22438186.0], field #1['created_at']: [MinKey, MaxKey]",
                    "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                    "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                    "matchTested" : 0,
                    "keysExamined" : 9,
                    "children" : []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Hope that clears up the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

If you see the `explain()` plan, you can see that:

```
db.tweets.find({user:22438186})
```

uses the `user_1` index.

`db.tweets.find({user:22438186}).sort({created_at:1})` uses the `created_at_1` index.

This indicates that mongodb has chosen `created_at_1` over `user_1` for the fact that sort operations perform better when they use an index, and the sort operation is based on the `created_at` field. That makes `mongodb` ignore the `user_1` index and perform a `full collection scan`.

So we need to define our [indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-and-non-prefix-subset-of-an-index) carefully in these cases. If we have a compound index on both `user_1` and `created_at_1`, a full table scan will not occur and mongodb will choose the index that supports both the `find` and the `sort` operations, which in case would be the compound index.

[JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14585) has a beautiful explanation why mongoDB uses the `QueryOptimizerCursor` cursor.

> *nscannedObjectsAllPlans / nscannedAllPlans drop down to 29*

You should not be worrying about these two parameters, they are a representation of the combined scans made by all the plans that mongodb has executed to select the appropriate index.

> nscannedObjectsAllPlans is a number that reflects the total number of
>   documents scanned for all query plans during the database operation
>
> nscannedAllPlans is a number that reflects the total number of
>   documents or index entries scanned for all query plans during the
>   database operation.

These lines are from the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#explain.nscannedObjectsAllPlans).

> *So what exactly is causing my documents to be scanned twice when limit() and sort() are both used in a find()?*

As said, the documents are not scanned twice, they are [scanned](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-plans/#query-plans) in parallel by two different plans executed by mongodb to select the appropriate index. If you have two different indexes, two plans may be run in parallel., and so on.

Comment: Thanks, I came across the JIRA link while doing further research, I understand the QueryOptimizerCursor was likely doing an ordered and unordered search? Hence why nscannedObjects was double the returned documents(and the cursor clauses data being exactly the same).  
  
I don't think I was clear enough with the results/codeblocks I had in the original question, I've provided a detailed update/clarification. The `create_at_1` index doesn't seem to be chosen for that query, only used by the planner.

Comment: It appears the *nscannedAllPlans* fields are just cached results and I should only be concerned about the *n* / *nscanned* / *nscannedObjects* fields. Which is what my question is mostly about, when the `QueryOptimizerCursor` is the active/used cursor the scanned indexes/documents was double what they should be. I'm trying to understand why that is.

Comment: @BatScream Does this issue arise only in sort and limit? Thanks for nice explanation.